# Lookahead with sub-regular expression

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have some data (to be precise this data comes from Windows Registry), which looks like that:

```
some data ... PACKAGE_SIZE    REG_SZ    100000\r\n    PATH    REG_SZ    C:\\Some\\path\r\n    VERSION    REG_SZ    1.0.0\r\n some other data...
```

I need to extract the path from it, so I use a regular expression like that:

```
(?<=(PATH.*?REG_SZ)).+?(?=\\r\\n)
```

But it doesn't work, as I understand because the lookaround is atomic. So far I'm able to use something like that:

```
(?<=PATH).+?(?=\\r\\n)
```

what captures

```
    REG_SZ    C:\\Some\\path
```

My question is - is this possible to extract the path in one go? (It means without using two regular expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
String data="some data ... PACKAGE_SIZE    REG_SZ    100000\r\n    PATH    REG_SZ    C:\\Some\\path\r\n    VERSION    REG_SZ    1.0.0\r\n some other data";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("PATH\\s+REG_SZ\\s+(.*)\\r\\n");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

output: `C:\Some\path`

Comment: ``\\s+`` would not work. As ``java does not supports infinitive repetitions within lookbehind``. Isnt it?

Comment: `(?:` was not lookbehind :) anyway I changed it to easier regexp

Comment: What do you mean? What is missing?

Comment: ``(PATH\\s+REG_SZ\\s+(.*?)\\r\\n`` contains one ``(`` and two ``)``. Haven't you still notice that?

Comment: Thank you for info, I edited that answer few times before and missed that bracket (probably starting to get blind). Now it should work fine :)

Comment: You are right, using groups actually I don't need to use lookaround at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=PATH\\s{1,10}REG_SZ\\s{1,10})(\\S[^\r\n]+)(?=\r\n)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

### IMPORTANT:

***Assuming number of spaces between `PATH`, `REG_SZ` and `matched data` sould be varied from 1-10.***